# When is a comment not a comment? Off-topic close with custom reason (comment) yields auto-flag for commentless close

Tags: bug, flags, close-dialog

I closed [this question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/9164/1993) as off-topic/other, adding a comment via the close dialogue.  I'm a mod, so my close vote was binding.  A moment later, I got an auto-flag on that post: "closed w/o comment".

Apparently the bot doesn't consider all comments to be comments.

This happened again with [this questioon](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/4839/1993), so it's not a fluke.  There's also no reason to believe this behavior is specific to Writers.SE; I know the bot runs on other sides, and its behavior is likely to be the same.

Comment: Should this be on http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Depends if the bot is writers.stackexchange.com specific or a stack exchange wide bot

Comment: I've seen those flags on Mi Yodeya (where I'm also a moderator), so I assumed the bot was general.  I sure can't think of a reason why Writers would have custom auto-flagging code.

Comment: Love the word *"questioon"* and want to use it as a derogatory term for bad questions. A mix between question and spittoon.

Comment: Sigh -- some days the typos just flock to me, it seems. ("Sides", too -- I meant "sites".) :-(  I'm not going to edit just for that, but if somebody edits for some other reason, I hope it'll include fixing those. :-)